# What is meant by viewing a tree as a chain of nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I was reading couple of articles on heavy light decomposition of trees. There I kept getting this chaining terms which I find very difficult to understand.

Could someone please explain how any tree not necessarily a binary tree and does not necessarily have a root and unordered CAN be viewed as just a chain of nodes ? (In simple language) A small example or code snippet would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: I am referring to this article: https://blog.anudeep2011.com/heavy-light-decomposition/

Comment: I think the issue may be that "chain" does not mean what you think it means. In particular in general trees are not linear graphs or even disconnected unions of such. Can you define "chain" from your sources?

Comment: I am referring to this article https://blog.anudeep2011.com/heavy-light-decomposition/

Comment: What makes you think that any tree can be viewed as a chain of nodes?  I don't see any statement of that sort in what you linked.

Comment: The article decomposes a tree into a set of chains (in a particular way). Some of the chains only contain one node.